# Xamarin.Forms UWP Project The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I have a basic Xamarin.Forms app with UWP, Android and iOS projects, it's using the .NET Standard for code sharing.

In one of my pages (in the common project) I've put a breakpont on the constructor and it's not being hit when i set the UWP as the StartUp project. It tells me that it won't be hit because the symbols have not been loaded. 
When I set the Android project as the Startup it hits the break point.

It's pretty much an out of the box solution with very little in it so I'm confused why this is happening.

Can anyone shed any light on this for me please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that this is a [known issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/955) that is supposed to be [fixed](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/1951).

It looks like you can fix this by changing the `.NET Standard` project config and set the `DebugType` to `pdbonly`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Another option could be by following these steps:

> In the Core Project (.NET Standart Project or Xamarin.UWP)> Properties > Compilation > Advanced > Select "PDB Only"

[image: build settings screenshot]

Comment: I used the steps to set the Debugging Information to pdb-only and I'm now able to step through the code. Thanks for the help Paul.

Comment: For me it only worked when i changed Solution configuration from x86 to x64.